# Dynamic dispatching

Tags: ada

I have a reasonable amount of experience with Ada, but I have never used objects before. I found I had to use them to avoid the complications of not null access discriminate record types with task safe data structures. I need to make a function that takes in a base class and based on an if statement do dynamic dispatching, but I get an "incompatible types" error if the type I am testing is not in the class in the conditional. Is what I want to do impossible in Ada?

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Dispatch is
  type foo is tagged record
    bar : boolean;
  end record;
  type foo2 is new foo with record
    bar2 : boolean;
  end record;
  type foo3 is new foo with record
    bar3 : boolean;
  end record;
  f3 : foo3;
  procedure Do_Something(fubar : in out foo'class) is
  begin
    if fubar in foo2'class then
      fubar.bar2 := True;
    end if;
  end Do_Something;
begin
  Do_Something(f3);
end Dispatch;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, your code fails to compile with `dispatch.adb:16:15: no selector “bar2" for type “foo'class" defined at line 3`; nothing about incompatible types.

Anyway, the problem with the code as posted  is that there is no component `bar2` in `foo`; the only components visible in an object through a view of type `foo’class` are those in an object of type `foo`.

To get round this, you can change the view of `fubar` to `foo2`:

```
if fubar in foo2'class then
   foo2 (fubar).bar2 := true;
end if;
```

However, this is *not* dispatching! To get a dispatching call you need

- a primitive operation in the base type (none here)
- a class-wide object or pointer (OK)

and you need a more complicated example, because you can only declare primitive operations in a package spec. Something like

```
package Dispatch is
   type Foo is tagged record
      Bar : Boolean;
   end record;
   procedure Update (F : in out Foo; B : Boolean) is null;  -- primitive
   type Foo2 is new Foo with record
      Bar2 : Boolean;
   end record;
   overriding procedure Update (F : in out Foo2; B : Boolean);
   type Foo3 is new Foo with record
      Bar3 : Boolean;
   end record;  -- inherits default Update
end Dispatch;

package body Dispatch is
   procedure Update (F : in out Foo2; B : Boolean) is
   begin
      F.Bar2 := B;
   end Update;
end Dispatch;

procedure Dispatch.Main is
   F3 : Foo3;
   procedure Do_Something(Fubar : in out Foo'Class) is
   begin
      Fubar.Update (True);  -- dispatches
   end Do_Something;
begin
   Do_Something(F3);
end Dispatch.Main;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for the error in terminology. I am having a related issue I am hoping you could also help me with. I would like to make a generic package that takes in a base class type but I get an error "aggregate cannot be of a class-wide type". `generic F : Foo'class; package food is Junk : Boolean; end Food; package ZFood is new Food(f => (foo with bar2 => true));`

Comment: Glad that helped. Please ask a new question about the related issue.